# How do I link gtkmm with g++ on linux

Tags: c++, g++

I am creating a GUI with C++. So I installed gtkmm using the terminal line:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-dev
```

and included gtkmm using `#include <gtkmm.h>`. But when I followed a tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE9XIhif6oE) and compiled my code:

```
g++ example.cpp -o out  `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I see an error:

```
In file included from example.cpp:1:0:
cross.hpp: In member function ‘void crossStd::gui_class::createWindow(int, int,std::__cxx11::string)’:
cross.hpp:95:9: error: ‘Gtk’ has not been declared
     Gtk::Main kit(argc,argv);
     ^~~
cross.hpp:96:9: error: ‘Gtk’ has not been declared
     Gtk::Window window;
```

I does not seem like it is linking gtkmm. What should I do to properly link gtk?

Comment: You say "link" but you mean "compile."  There is no linking problem here because your code does not compile, so the linker never runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate include statement is:

```
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
```

That's according to the docs: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Main.html

And you should always compile with `-Wall` to enable warnings, which might have told you that your `#include <gtkmm.h>` did not find any file.